# Concatenate every 2 rows in a single column table

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

This is the code I used to concatenate the first two rows which each have 6 characters each. Each row of data is set at 6.

My problem is it only returns the first concatenate needed and doesn't effect the next rows.

```
DECLARE @r_strands VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @r_strands=''

SELECT  @r_strands= @r_strands + R_Strands
FROM    rs_table
SELECT  LEFT(@r_strands, +12) AS text

     rs_table

     r_strands 
    thedog 
    wentto 
    hisbed 
    wherei 
    placed 
    foodto 
    eatfor 
    supper
```

the above is an example of the single column table I want to concat every two rows

```
EX. result desired

 r_strands 
 thedogwentto 
 hisbedwherei 
 placedfoodto 
 eatforsupper
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: i edited the initial posting so you have an idea of what the table looks like

Comment: How do you determine the order?

Comment: order is determined by sequence. so row 1 then row 2 then row 3 and 4.

Comment: No, a table has no defined order, unless you specify an `order by` in the query.

Comment: I added an id column so i could order by id

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to make pairs of two consecutive `r_strands`. Then use `FOR XML PATH('')` for concatenation:

*If you have an `Id` to determine the order, you can replace the `ORDER BY` with `Id` instead of `SELECT NULL`.*

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82149/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + 1) / 2
    FROM rs_table
)
SELECT
    r_strands = (
        SELECT '' + r_strands
        FROM Cte
        WHERE RN = c.RN
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
    )
FROM Cte c
GROUP BY RN
```

**RESULT**:

```
|    r_strands |
|--------------|
| thedogwentto |
| hisbedwherei |
| placedfoodto |
| eatforsupper |
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have an row number column (call it "id"), you can self join adjacent columns on the id, and concatenate the strings using the + string concatination operator:

```
select a.r_strands + b.r_strands
from rs_table a
join rs_table b
on a.id = b.id - 1
```

Comment: I like this simple code very much but im getting an error when I use the "|" Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the '|' operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (id int, r_strands varchar(100));
insert into @t values
(1, 'thedog'), 
(2, 'wentto'), 
(3, 'hisbed'), 
(4, 'wherei'), 
(5, 'placed'), 
(6, 'foodto'), 
(7, 'eatfor'), 
(8, 'supper');

select r_strands + next_row
from
(
    select *,
           next_row =  lead(r_strands) over(order by id),
           is_mod   = id % 2
    from @t
) x
where is_mod != 0;
```